# Unable to upload videos to imgur with javascript

Tags: javascript, imgur

I am able to upload images as binary files to imgur endpoint `https://api.imgur.com/3/image`. As the [documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) states, we can upload videos as well using the `video` key instead of `image` key, but I am unable to.

I successfully uploaded a gif file using the exact same code below but instead of `video` key, I provided the required `image` key. But if I try to upload an mp4 or webm file with the `video` key it says "No image data was sent to the upload api". And, if I provide the video binary file into an `image` key it gives me a 500 status.

```
function uploadFileToImgur(outputFileLocation) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(outputFileLocation, (err, data) => {

      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }

      const uploadHeaders = {
        Authorization: 'Client-ID ' + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID,
      };

      let formDataOptions = {
        'type': 'file'
      };

      const fileType = getFileType(outputFileLocation);
      if (!fileType) {
        reject('Wrong filetype');
      }

      if (fileType === 'image') {
        formDataOptions['image'] = data;
      } else {
        formDataOptions['video'] = data;
      }

      const uploadPostOptions = {
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        headers: uploadHeaders,
        formData: formDataOptions
      };

      requestMaker.post(uploadPostOptions, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The API responds with

```
{
  "data": {
    "error": "No image data was sent to the upload api",
    "request": "/3/image",
    "method": "POST"
  },
  "success": false,
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Well, the endpoint in the documentation is `https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` and in your code it's `https://api.imgur.com/3/image`

Comment: Yes, I had tried ```https://api.imgur.com/3/upload``` as well, and it does not work either. It gives me the same 400 response.